# public JSONObject (String json) in api19 scrambles order?

Tags: android, json

I was parsing a string to a JSONObject and noticed some weird behaviour. The orders of items get scrambled? Is this a bug or did i do something wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 'items' are key/value pairs in a JSON object. 
The order of key/value pairs within a JSON object is not guaranteed:

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.

If you need to preserve the order of those items you can put them in an array on the serializing side (probably a server):

> An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an
>   array, vector, list, or sequence.

[Official docs.](http://json.org/)